# Extjs 5. Automatically delete special symbols ( like !#$%( ) in the grid textfield

Tags: extjs

I want to use these special symbols, but I cannot find where they can be replaced.

I look at example: [cell-editing](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#cell-editing) - there is a problem here.

But if I look at easy textfield without grid and cell editing :[form-fieldtypes](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#form-fieldtypes) - it's ok, np

And further: navigation is missing in textfield if it's in a grid and navigation is present if it's an easy textfield

What is the difference?

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?295892-Ext-JS-5.1-Post-GA-Patches&p=1080371&viewfull=1#post1080371

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in 5.1 version. In 5.0 all is fine. Test in [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2d) with different versions.